# Javascript function if statement

Tags: javascript, html, function, event-listener

I am making a dice game on javascript where you bet if the outcome will be ODD or EVEN , and when you press the button the dice will roll and it will show if it is odd or even. My only problem is that when you bet even and you get an odd it wont record it as a loss or if you bet even and get even it wont record as a win. To summarize I dont know why it doesnt record the score of the player. All help is appreciated please and thank you, also code is down here.

```js
var score = 0;
var lose = 0;
document.getElementById("Even").addEventListener("click", Evencheck);

function Evencheck() {
  var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var d11 = parseInt(d1);
  var d22 = parseInt(d2);
  var d33 = parseInt(d11 + d22);
  die1.innerHTML = "Dice 1 rolled: " + d1;
  die2.innerHTML = "Dice 2 rolled: " + d2;
  sum.innerHTML = " Total Sum: " + d33;
  if (d33 % 2 == 0 && Even.Clicked) {
    var score = score + 1;
    wins.innerHTML = " Wins : " + score;
    losses.innerHTMl = " Losses : " + lose;
  }
  if (d33 % 2 == 1 && Even.Clicked) {
    var lose = lose + 1;
    wins.innerHTML = " Wins : " + score;
    losses.innerHTMl = " Losses : " + lose;
  }
}
document.getElementById("Odd").addEventListener("click", Oddcheck);

function Oddcheck() {
  var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  var d11 = parseInt(d1);
  var d22 = parseInt(d2);
  var d33 = parseInt(d11 + d22);
  die1.innerHTML = "Dice 1 rolled: " + d1;
  die2.innerHTML = "Dice 2 rolled: " + d2;
  sum.innerHTML = " Total Sum: " + d33;
  if (d33 % 2 == 0 && Odd.Clicked) {
    var lose = lose + 1;
    wins.innerHTML = " Wins : " + score;
    losses.innerHTMl = " Losses : " + lose;
  }
  if (d33 % 2 == 1 && Odd.Clicked) {
    var score = score + 1;
    wins.innerHTML = " Wins : " + score;
    losses.innerHTMl = " Losses : " + lose;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="defaults.css">
  <title>INTRO</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <h1><img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50"> EVEN ODDS<img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50"> </h1>
  <div id="die1" class="dice"> Dice1 :0</div>
  <div id="die2" class="dice"> Dice2 :0</div>
  <div id="sum" class="dicesum"> Sum :0</div>
  <div id="wins" class="score"> Wins :0</div>
  <div id="losses" class="lose"> Losses :0</div>
  <button class="Even" onclick="Evencheck()">Even</button>
  <button class="Odd" onclick="Oddcheck()">ODD</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The calls to `parseInt()` are pointless. The numbers are already integers.

Comment: Also what do you expect `Even.Clicked` and `Odd.Clicked` to mean?

Comment: @Pointy well the thing is , it started working when I used parseInt ( it wasnt displaying the sum number when i didnt have parse int on) and I confused it with the .click() command, i changed it but its still not working

Comment: @Pointy I believe `parseInt` will cause them to be truncated to integers from whatever they were previously. Doesn't make much of a difference with the result of `Math.floor`, but...

Comment: @HereticMonkey it will first convert the numbers back to strings, and then return basically exactly the same value, because (as you noted) they're already numbers with no fractional part.

Comment: @AHHHHHHHH do you understand how to use your browser's Console to check for errors? as you can see from the runnable demo above (which prints from the console onto the screen directly), your code fails almost immediately because you aren't binding to the buttons correctly. You don't have any buttons with the IDs "Even" or "Odd" - you set them as classes instead. If you were checking for errors you might have found that before now. Learning to use the Console (and the other parts of the Developer Tools) will be a vital skill so you can debug your code effectively and write good JS apps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you had several bugs in your code -

1. "Even" & "Odd" were classes and not ids so you couldn't bind it - replace the class attribute with id attribute.
2. you're if statements didn't worked, since you separated your code to odd and Even you just need to check if the num is odd or event and not which button was clicked - removed it from the statments.
3. your code didn't recognise the html elements for win and losses - so i handle it with add getelemntbyid.
4. you made score and lose global variables but you redeclare them, so you didn't got the right value there i remove the var declaration from the variables in the functions.
5. most important i recommend you to do it in one function which get params, and not 2 functions that handle each case.

try the following-

```
<h1><img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50">
    EVEN ODDS<img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50"> <h1><img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50">
    EVEN ODDS<img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50"> </h1>
<div id="die1" class="dice"> Dice1 :0</div>
<div id="die2" class="dice"> Dice2 :0</div>
<div id="sum" class="dicesum"> Sum :0</div>
<div id = "wins" class="score"> Wins :0</div>
<div id = "losses" class="lose"> Losses :0</div>
<button type="button" onclick="clicked(this.name)" name="even">Even</button>
<button type="button" onclick="clicked(this.name)" name="odd">ODD</button>

 <script>
  let score = 0;
  let lose = 0;
  const losses = document.getElementById("losses");
  const wins = document.getElementById("wins");
  function clicked(name){
    var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var d2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var d11 = parseInt(d1);
    var d22 = parseInt(d2);
    var d33 = parseInt(d11 + d22);
            const result = d33 % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
    die1.innerHTML = "Dice 1 rolled: " + d1;
    die2.innerHTML = "Dice 2 rolled: " + d2;
    sum.innerHTML = " Total Sum: " + d33;
    if( name === result) {
        score++;
      } else {
        lose++
    }
    wins.innerHTML = " Wins : " + score;
    losses.innerHTML = " Losses : " + lose;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, ver helpful and detailed explanation, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You got some small logic errors, I'd recommend you to take advantage of JavaScript, you can just have a *"main"* module (lets call it `play()`) where you can handle your game's logic.

Also, if you ain't using the DOM references you defined, it's always better to remove them. The less code, the better. (most of the time)

Look at the following corrections:

## What changed?:

- Added a *"log"* div so the player can see what is happening.
- Removed unused DOM references.
- Added `play()` function, which handles everything of your game.
- Added `rollDice()` function, which rolls the amount of dices you want.

And that's it, less code, a lot more human-readable, and working. Give it a test:

```js
let won = 0;
let lost = 0;
    
function rollDice(amount=1) { // A module that rolls the amount dices you want
  let dices = [];
  for(let c=0;c<amount;c++) {
    dices.push(+Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  }
  return dices; // Returns it as an array
}

function play(selection) {
  let dices = rollDice(2); // Roll two dices
  let sum = dices[0] + dices[1];
  die1.innerHTML = "Dice 1 rolled: " + dices[0];
  die2.innerHTML = "Dice 2 rolled: " + dices[1];
  res.innerHTML = " Total Sum: " + sum;
  let result = sum % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd"; // Ternary if statement to get the result
  log.innerHTML = `
    You selected ${selection} and result is ${result}.
    You ${selection===result ? "won" : "lost"}.
  `;
  if(selection===result) { // If statement that handles score based on result
    won++;
  } else {
    lost++;
  }
  wins.innerHTML = "Wins: " + won; // Update both results on screen after played
  losses.innerHTML = "Losses: " + lost;
}
```

```html
<img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50">
<h1>EVEN</h1>
<h1>ODDS</h1>
<img src="dice.png" alt="dice" width="50" height="50">
<div id="die1" class="dice"> Dice1 :0</div>
<div id="die2" class="dice"> Dice2 :0</div>
<div id="res" class="dicesum"> Sum :0</div>
<div id="wins" class="score"> Wins :0</div>
<div id="losses" class="lose"> Losses :0</div>
<button class="even" name="even" onclick="play(this.name)">Even</button>
<button class="odd" name="odd" onclick="play(this.name)">ODD</button>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much , you also explained it very clear. Appreciate it bless up :) ( i upvoted)

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing functions that take inputs and produce outputs -

```js
const roll = (sides = 6) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * sides) + 1
   
const isWin = (sum, bet) =>
  (sum & 1) === bet

const update = (bet, state) =>
{ const d1 = roll()
  const d2 = roll()
  const sum = d1 + d2

  return Object.assign
    ( state
    , { d1, d2, sum }
    , isWin(sum, bet)
        ? { win: state.win + 1 }
        : { loss: state.loss + 1 }
    )
}

const render = (form, state) =>
  Object
    .entries(state)
    .forEach(([ k, v ]) => form[k].value = v)
 
const play = (form, bet, state) =>
  render
    ( form
    , update(bet, state)
    )

// init
const state =
  { d1: 0, d2: 0, sum: 0, win: 0, loss: 0 }

const f = document.querySelector("form")
f.evenbet.addEventListener("click", event => play(f, 0, state))
f.oddbet.addEventListener("click", event => play(f, 1, state))

render(f, state)
```

```html
<form>
  Dice: <output name="d1"></output> <output name="d2"></output><br>
  Sum: <output name="sum"></output><br>
  <br>
  Win: <output name="win"></output> &nbsp; 
  Loss: <output name="loss"></output><br>
  Bet:
  <button type="button" name="oddbet">Odd</button>
  <button type="button" name="evenbet">Even</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Clicking *even* button always updates `loss` value +1. Logical error.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I added the missing `()` in my `isWin` function ^^